# Time arrival program with velocity change

Tags: python, algorithm, math, physics

i need help to think the idea of programming for this problem.
The program is to create estimated time arrival.

```
The car have this rule:
When 0km < x <= 6km , Velocity is 24KM/H
When 6km < x <= 10km, Velocity is 33KM/H
When x>10km, Velocity is 30KM/H

Input : 45.0
        10:30

Output : 12:28

The first input is distance and second input is time departured. The output is time arrival
Time format used (24-Hour) & Velocity format used (Metric)
```

Explanation

The car velocity is changed at specific distance, so example the distance is 45 KM, so when at first 6KM the velocity is 24KM/H, when the car at 7KM the velocity is changed to 33KM/H until 10KM, and more than 10KM the velocity is 30KM/H until 45KM

I really confused when the '12.28' come from, so i can't write the program if i even don't know. I already did calculate of average speed like 6*24 = 144, 4*33=132, 35*30 = 1050.

Average speed : (144+132+1050)/45 = 29,467 KM/H. But when i used calculator online to estimated speed of 12:28-10:30 = 1:58.

The speed is distance/time ==> 45/1.966666666666667 = 22.88135593220339 KM/H.

My result so far from calculator.

Simple sketch :
[image]

Comment: I don't think it's to do with averages, more like `t = sigma(d / s)`

Comment: There is a definition gap between 6 and 7 km. Which speed should be taken at  e.g. 6.2 or 6.7 km?

Comment: `distance / velocity = time`

Comment: And there is a problem with the example output. Does "12.28" mean "12:28" (which is 12 + 28/60) or does it mean decimal fraction 12 + 28/100?

Comment: @Mokshyam sorry i don't even understand why the output like that. So i still not make program.

Comment: @MichaelButscher No, i think the program doesnt even care about acceleration from the 6 to 7 km. so more like when 0-6 km (the difference is 6) is 24km/h while 7km-10km (the difference is 4) is 30km/h. More like when 6.2/6.5/6.7 is always 24km/h. Ah sorry yeah it's mean 12:28 . It's typo

Comment: It's not about acceleration, there is no speed defined for 6 to 7km at all. The difference between 7km (in the sense of 7.00km) and 10.00km is 3km, not 4km, so for the range 0km-10km one kilometer is missing (undefined).

Comment: @MichaelButscher the difference is not 10-7 but 7,8,9,10 which is 4. or in another way like 6km to 7km is 33 Km/h i think. My comment 'More like when 6.2/6.5/6.7 is always 24km/h' is false then. Because the speed 24km/h is until 6km. More than that like 6.2/6.4 is changed to 33km/h

Comment: This would mean that the `33km/h` speed would apply up to <11.00km and the `>10km` actually means >=11.00km?

Comment: @MichaelButscher No speed 33km/h is until 10km. More than 10km like 10.5/10.8 and continuously is changed to 30km/h.

Comment: So the precise km ranges are `0.0 to <6.5`,  `6.5 to <10.5` and `>=10.5`?

Comment: @MichaelButscher hmm i think `0.0 < x  <= 6` , `6 <  x  <= 10` and `>10` the number is float is think so 6.0 still 24km/h but when decimal changed little bit like 6.01 the speed is changed to 33km/h

Comment: But why it says `7-10KM` if `6 to <=10` is meant? It's just confusing.

Comment: @MichaelButscher okay i will changed it, the problem task is write like that :(

Comment: I guess that whoever wrote this task didn't thoroughly think it through.

Comment: Can you quote the problem *exactly* as stated? You're calculating the wrong thing. Still, I get an expected time of arrival of 12:02 and I suspect something is off about your numbers. Or the problem is just wrong.

Comment: `(6 / 24 + 4 / 33 + 35 / 30) * 60 = 92.27272727272728`. The travel should take `1:32:27.3`, not nearly 2 hours. The numbers are definitely off here.

Answer (score 0):

The given example is provably wrong. As you correctly wrote to calculate the average speed of the sample trip:

> The speed is distance/time ==> 45/1.966666666666667 =
>   22.88135593220339 KM/H

The rule speeds for the car are in the range 24 to 33 km/h. This means that average speed of every trip driven with this car must also be in this range but the sample trip has a lower average speed so it can't be correct.